# Wrap timecode into brackets using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

In a string, I need all timecodes to be formatted as following [HH:MM:SS] or [HH:MM:SS.ms]. Some of them are already in brackets. They can be everywhere, beginning, middle, or end of a phrase.

I'd like to put those not in brackets in brackets.

To select all of them I use:

```
[\[]?\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(.\d+)?[\]]?
```

I tried

```
(?!\[.+\])(.|^)(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d(.\d+)?)(.|$)(?!\[.+\])
```

Which is almost fine except that my selection `$2` includes space characters in the case of string not beggining by ^ or finishing by $.

How can I get rid of this selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.sub(r'\[?\b(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\.\d+)?)\b]?', r'[\1]', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mULGiO/1). *Details*:

- `\[?` - an optional `[` char
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1:

  - `\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}` - two digits, and then two occurrences of `:` and two digits
  - `(?:\.\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` and one or more digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `]?` - an optional `]` char

To make sure you match 24-hour time format you can use a more precise pattern:

```
\[?\b((?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9](?:\.[0-9]+)?)\b]?
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/PYOETM/3).